# Как вывести дату в переменную

Tags: javascript, html

```
<input type="text" value="dd-mm-yy" onfocus="this.select();_Calendar.lcs(this)"
onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;this.select();_Calendar.lcs(this) ">


document.write("Как вывести сюда дату?")
```

Comment: `let d = Date.now()`.

Comment: Мне это известно! Нужен ответ КАК записать в переменную из "VALUE"

Comment: <input type="text" value="dd-mm-yy" onfocus="this.select();_Calendar.lcs(this)"
 onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;this.select();_Calendar.lcs(this) ">    Просто в заголовке вопроса все не уместилось.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.write(Date());
```

Думаю как то так

Answer (score 0):

```
var d=new Date();
var day=d.getDate();
var month=d.getMonth() + 1;
var year=d.getFullYear();
document.write(day + "." + month + "." + year);
document.write("<br /><br />");
document.write(year + "/" + month + "/" + day);
```

Результат:

```
7.2.2017
2017/2/7
```